# Does Haskell allow use of keywords in identifiers?

Tags: haskell, keyword, identifier

C# allows it if you put an @ before the variable name. So
int @int = 0; 
is valid in C#.

Does Haskell have anything similar to this or it doesn't allow it altogether?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some words are keywords in some contexts but can be freely used as identifiers in others, such as `as` and `hiding`.

The C# trick is nothing but just slightly changing the name so that is it no longer a keyword. In Haskell, you could put a `_` before or after the name, or append a `'`.

Comment: `_` in the front of a binding has the additional meaning of "don't warn me if I don't use that binding", though.

Comment: In C# the name stays the same, for example `int @a = 0; f(a);` runs f(0).

Comment: Try to use '@int' in place of '@a' and you will freak the compiler out when you try to call 'f' with just 'int' and not '@int'

Comment: I thought @int would be how u tell the compiler that the variable's name is "int" e.g. were it a member field of a class, reflection api would show "int" instead of "@int". In Scala u can use backticks to escape: ``val `int` = 5``

Answer (score 3):

It appears that it is not allowed.  Note that you can usually put `'` after a keyword (since that is a valid identifier character) and get a non-keyword.

Comment: GHC also specially allows `#`.

Comment: But `#` has a conventional meaning in some contexts (such as for types it means unboxed).  Similarly a `'` usually means a derivative of or a strict version of the preceding name.